# Map2 for every row of dataframe and bind output

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function (prevalence package) that estimates the true prevalence of a pathogen given the number positive (x) and the number sampled (n). The function requires jags to be loaded on the computer for Bayesian estimation. Here is the function for a single entry along with output:

```
truePrev(x=432, n=1122, SE= ~ dbeta(13.67,3.95), SP= ~ dbeta(15.79,1.30))

mean median  mode    sd  2.5% 97.5%
TP 0.444  0.443 0.434 0.102 0.233 0.651
SE 0.766  0.776 0.796 0.098 0.559 0.926
SP 0.915  0.933 0.972 0.068 0.740 0.995

Multivariate BGR statistic = 1.0014
BGR values substantially above 1 indicate lack of convergence
```

Now I'm trying to iterate that function across a data frame of 500 plus rows using purrr map2:

```
df<- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3), "x" = c(5,10,15), "n" = c(20,25,30))
df_out<-map2(.x = x, .y= n, truePrev,SE=~ dbeta(13.67,3.95), SP=~ 
dbeta(15.79,1.30))
```

I can get the output, but want to bind it to the original data frame so that it corresponds to the correct ID row. I've been looking through Stack Overflow, but the format of this output has kept some of the other suggestions I've read from working. When I try to change the output from a list to a data frame, I get this error:

```
as.data.frame(df_out)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class ‘structure("prev", package = "prevalence")’ to a 
data.frame
```

Comment: so, if you have `x` and `n` in a dataframe `df`, you should be able to just put your `map2` results into a new column with `dplyr`. Does `df %>% mutate(truePrev = map2(.x = x, .y= n, truePrev, SE=~ dbeta(13.67,3.95), SP=~ dbeta(15.79,1.30)) )` not work?

Comment: This is the output from adding a new column with dplyr:                                       
    geoid   neg     x     n truePrev
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>  
 1 35027   690   432  1122 <prev>  
 2 32033   682    65   747 <prev>  
 3 53007   539     1   540 <prev>  ...

Comment: That doesn't look very revealing, but it's exactly what I think you'd want. Within the list column you have in each cell the output of your truePrev function for the given row. If there is one specific value generated by this function, obviously you can extract that and instead only write this one value into a column.

Comment: Agreed. Sorry, was trying to respond before being pulled away. Wanted to show the output is lists within a list and haven't had luck extracting. Have tried unnest, but get an error that input must be list of vectors. Thought there might be a way to do this within purrr that I was missing, but maybe not. Miight close and repost as an extraction question.

Comment: Can you describe how you would want this to be unnested? What would you want to have added to your data frame in each row?

Comment: I pinged the author of the function. Since the function output is a series of complex S4 objects, they suggested an appropriate extract function to get to the main output:              
extract <-
function(x) {
  c(apply(as.matrix(x), 2,
          function(y) c(mean(y), quantile(y, c(0.5, .025, .975)))))
}

p <- truePrev(1, 10)
extract(p)